# Commands don't echo after sudo as another user

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, terminal

I have a single command to ssh to a remote linux host and execute a shell script.

`ssh -t -t $USER@somehost 'bash -s' < ./deploy.sh`

Inside `deploy.sh` I have this:

```
#!/bin/bash

whoami;                 # I see this command echo
sudo -i -u someoneelse  #I see this command echo
whoami;                 # I DON'T see this command echo, but response is correct

#subsequent commands don't echo
```

When I run the `deploy.sh` script locally all commands echo.

How do I get commands to echo after I sudo as another user over ssh?

Comment: Id not use sudo in the script in the first place.  its very insecure and you should call the script as sudo if the script needs those privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Had to `set -x` AFTER sudo as another user

```
#!/bin/bash

whoami;
sudo -i -u someonelese
set -x              #make sure echo on
whoami;             #command echoed
```